# TortoiseCVS - seeing revisions log

Tags: version-control, cvs, tortoisecvs

I'm used to TrotoiseSVN and installed TortoiseCVS now. 
How do I see a log of the revisions in Tortoise CVS?

Answer (score 5):

1. RigthClick on a file or folder
2. go in CVS subMenu,
3. select [Command...]
4. type [log] (without brace + press Enter)
5. wait a little and the log will apear